# Unable to View image file from S3 without downloading - #python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

In my python code, I need a URL that would **view** the image. But the URL obtained after running the code below is actually **downloading** the image from the S3 bucket rather than displaying it.

Can you please suggest how to upload to S3 and obtain a URL for displaying without downloading?

```py
#upload is done through the below code
import os
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource(
    service_name='s3',
    region_name='region',
    aws_access_key_id='your personal access id',
    aws_secret_access_key='your personal secret key'
    )
    s3.meta.client.upload_file( 'your folder path', 'bucketname', 'key')

# url is obtained by below code
url = boto3.client(
    service_name='s3',
    region_name='region',
    aws_access_key_id='your personal access id',
    aws_secret_access_key='your personal secret key'
    ).generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object', 
    Params={'Bucket': 'bucketname', 'Key': 'name'},
    ExpiresIn=3600)
    print(url)
```

Comment: Are you saying that this code generates a pre-signed URL and you are then pasting this URL into a web browser? If the image is not correctly displayed, then make sure that the `Content-Type` metadata is being set when the object is uploaded. If you upload by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), then it will automatically set the `Content-Type`.

Comment: what changes should i make in my above python upload code inorder to view the object rather than downloading it when pasting the url in browser @JohnRotenstein

Comment: You need to define define the `Content-Type` as per the linked Answers.